# How to add data into Specified columns in mysql using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

How to add data into Specified columns in mysql database table using c# button click, once i clicked the button it will be passing to the catch

here is my add button code

```
 private void Button_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string Query = @"INSERT INTO `bcasdb`.`tbl_department`(
                `dep_id`,
                `dep_name`,
                `tbl_branch_branch_id`) 
        VALUES (" 
               + this.depIDInput.Text + ",'" 
               + this.depnameInput.Text + "','" 
               + this.dep_branchIDInput.Text + "')";
            //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(BCASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader MyReader;
            conn.Open();
            MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();// Here our query will be executed and data saved into the database.           
            conn.Close();
            successmsgBox();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errormsgBox();
        }
    }
```

here is all the columns of the table,

```
INSERT INTO `bcasdb`.`tbl_student`
(`reg_id`,
`std_fname`,
`std_lname`,
`tbl_batch_batch_id`,
`gender`,
`dob`,
`email`,
`mobile`,
`contact_address`,
`home_address`,
`status`,
`course_id`,
`depart_id`,
`parent_name`,
`telephone`,
`nationality`,
`nic`,
`passport_no`,
`acadamic_qulification`,
`current_employement`,
`gce_ol`,
`gce_al`,
`birth_certifiacte`,
`copy_of_nic`,
`police_clerence`,
`tbl_studentcol`)
VALUES
```

Comment: What exception are you getting

Comment: Your table has multiple columns and if all the columns are set to not null you will need to pass all values or set default values to the table structure. You are inserting correct with if columns, but your table needs all not null values. Due to which you are getting error message - I Suppose this could be a reason since you have not displayed error message in your question

Comment: I suspect you may want `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And since `INSERT` statement doesn't return any data, there is no point to use `ExecuteReader` here. Looks like you just need `ExecuteNonQuery`. And use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections.

Comment: To get a correct answer you need to tell us what is the error message catched by the exception handler (also the inner exception message if any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code should be rewritten as following:

```
    private void Button_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string Query = @"INSERT INTO `bcasdb`.`tbl_department`(
            `dep_id`,
            `dep_name`,
            `tbl_branch_branch_id`) 
            VALUES (@depId, @depName, @branchId)";
            //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(BCASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@depId", this.depIDInput.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dep_name", this.depnameInput.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@branchId", this.dep_branchIDInput.Text);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            successmsgBox();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errormsgBox();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fine but why ExecuteScalar? The correct method is ExecuteNonQuery that returns the number of rows added

Comment: @Steve you're probably right. ExecuteNonQuery is better in that case. I'll modify the answer.

Comment: but this is occuring some errors but this one gave me good idea to solve issuse, see my answer